# SVG Text are being truncated

Tags: javascript, css, svg, text, polygon

I currently working on the integration of an SVG map,i tried two technique to render this map, first one, first try was working well but really messy stuff regarding how the data was organized. Second one, really cleaner, but now it the text is being truncated when i render the map.

As you see we have the city *Renn* that is supposed to be **Rennaz**, *Chess* that is supposed to be **Chessel** and *Corbeyrie* that is supposed to be **Corbeyrier**

[image: Map Example]

#### Here is how i organize the data now:

```
[
  {
    id: generateRandomId(),
    name: 'Rennaz',
    map: {
      positionX: 42.7303,
      positionY: 230.0168,
      polygonClassModifier: `--lighter`,
      polygonPoints: `61.1,214.8 61.1,220.1 58.2,232.6 58.2,234.7 55.3,237 53.9,234.7 50.8,234.7 42.8,240 42.8,229.7
      42.8,224.4 50.8,222.2 47.8,220.1 55.3,214.8`,
    },
  },
  {
    id: generateRandomId(),
    name: 'Roche',
    map: {
      positionX: 50.8895,
      positionY: 249.4768,
      polygonClassModifier: `--medium-lighter`,
      polygonPoints: `58.2,232.6 65.6,234.7 70.7,232.6 73.6,232.6 75.8,234.7 75.8,237 78.1,240 78.1,242.9 81.1,240
      83.2,242.9 78.1,247.3 70.7,255.4 65.6,256.8 65.6,259.8 50.8,262.8 45.7,262.8 40.5,259.8 42.8,256.8 45.7,255.4 38.3,244.3
      40.5,240 42.8,240 50.8,234.7 53.9,234.7 55.3,237 58.2,234.7`,
    },
  },
...
]
```

#### How i render it (Vue.js)

```
  <svg
    :class="INTERACTIVE_MAP_CSS_CLASSES.svg"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    x="0px"
    y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 345.7 468.1"
    xml:space="preserve"
    pointer-events="auto"
  >
    <g v-for="city in communes" :key="city.id">
      <g>
        <polygon
          class="interactive-map__polygon"
          :points="city.map.polygonPoints"
          @click="$emit('onCommuneClick', city)"
        />
      </g>

      <text
        :transform="`matrix(1 0 0 1 ${city.map.positionX} ${city.map.positionY})`"
      >
        {{ city.name }}
      </text>

      <g
        v-if="city.map.hasPoint"
        :transform="`matrix(
          1 0 0 1 ${city.map.positionX - 6} ${city.map.positionY - 3.5}
        )`"
        stroke-width="3"
      >
        <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="2.5" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

#### Before when it was working (messy solution)

I would have 3 properties in a object

- the citiesName
- the pins(black filled circle)
- the polygons

```
export const interactiveMap = {
citiesName: [
    {
      id: generateRandomId(),
      name: 'Rennaz',
      transform: 'matrix(0.92 0 0 1 42.7303 230.0168)',
    },
    {
      id: generateRandomId(),
      name: 'Roche',
      transform: 'matrix(0.92 0 0 1 50.8895 249.4768)',
    },
],
pins: [
   {
      id: generateRandomId(),
      paths: [
        `M169.5,384.4L169.5,384.4c1.4,0,2.5,1.1,2.5,2.5l0,0c0,1.4-1.1,2.5-2.5,2.5l0,0c-1.4,0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5l0,0
        C167,385.5,168.1,384.4,169.5,384.4z`,
        `M169.5,386.1L169.5,386.1c0.4,0,0.8,0.3,0.8,0.7l0,0c0,0.4-0.3,0.7-0.7,0.7l0,0c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0
        C168.7,386.5,169,386.1,169.5,386.1z`,
      ],
    },
],
polygons: [
    {
      id: generateRandomId(),
      cssClass: `${POLYGONS_BASE_CSS_CLASS}--lighter`,
      points: `61.1,214.8 61.1,220.1 58.2,232.6 58.2,234.7 55.3,237 53.9,234.7 50.8,234.7 42.8,240 42.8,229.7
      42.8,224.4 50.8,222.2 47.8,220.1 55.3,214.8`,
    },
    {
      id: generateRandomId(),
      cssClass: `${POLYGONS_BASE_CSS_CLASS}--medium-lighter`,
      points: `58.2,232.6 65.6,234.7 70.7,232.6 73.6,232.6 75.8,234.7 75.8,237 78.1,240 78.1,242.9 81.1,240
      83.2,242.9 78.1,247.3 70.7,255.4 65.6,256.8 65.6,259.8 50.8,262.8 45.7,262.8 40.5,259.8 42.8,256.8 45.7,255.4 38.3,244.3
      40.5,240 42.8,240 50.8,234.7 53.9,234.7 55.3,237 58.2,234.7`,
    },

]
}
```

#### Messy solution render:

```
 <svg
    id="aas-map"
    class="interactive-map"
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    x="0px"
    y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 345.7 468.1"
    xml:space="preserve"
    pointer-events="auto"
  >
    <g>
      <polygon
        v-for="polygon in polygons"
        :key="polygon.id"
        class="interactive-map__polygon"
        :points="polygon.points"
      />
    </g>

    <text
      v-for="city in cities"
      :key="city.id"
      :transform="city.transform"
      class="interactive-map__city-name"
    >
      {{ city.name }}
    </text>

    <g
      v-for="pin in pins"
      :key="pin.id"
      class="interactive-map__pin"
    >
      <path v-for="path in pin.paths" :key="path" :d="path" />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

I believe it has something to do with the main  where i do my v-for, that's the only difference in the organisation between the two compared logic.

I've tried various things so far:

- edit some css properties (overflow:visible, z-index,...) not working
- tried to put the text before the polygon, but they are just being hidden by the polygon afterward
- Edit the matrix in the transform, not helped me too

If anyone has a clue, thanks for reaching out :)
Thanks

Comment: i tried to do so already, but adding zindex and relative position doesn't change anything sadly...

Comment: The text is overlapped by the next shape. One solution would be putting all the text in a group of it's own at the end of the svg. Also I would recomend changing the font size to something smaller. Since someone commented about z-index : z-index doesn't work in SVG

Answer (score 0):

As **@enxaneta** has pointed out:
you have to make sure, your labels are "on top" (decreasing font-size also makes sense).

In svg (like in html) these label elements would be written at the end/bottom of your svg markup.

So you need to seperate label output from your regular shape loop.
Probably there's a better way in vue.js to avoid a second list rendering.
The main idea of this snippet: both city areas and labels are added to a corresponding `<g>` element. (`<g id="city-areas" >` and `<g id="city-labels">`).

```js
var cities =
    [
  {
    id: 123,
    name: 'Rennaz',
    map: {
      positionX: 42.7303,
      positionY: 230.0168,
      polygonClassModifier: `--lighter`,
      polygonPoints: `61.1,214.8 61.1,220.1 58.2,232.6 58.2,234.7 55.3,237 53.9,234.7 50.8,234.7 42.8,240 42.8,229.7
      42.8,224.4 50.8,222.2 47.8,220.1 55.3,214.8`,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 456,
    name: 'Roche',
    map: {
      positionX: 50.8895,
      positionY: 249.4768,
      polygonClassModifier: `--medium-lighter`,
      polygonPoints: `58.2,232.6 65.6,234.7 70.7,232.6 73.6,232.6 75.8,234.7 75.8,237 78.1,240 78.1,242.9 81.1,240
      83.2,242.9 78.1,247.3 70.7,255.4 65.6,256.8 65.6,259.8 50.8,262.8 45.7,262.8 40.5,259.8 42.8,256.8 45.7,255.4 38.3,244.3
      40.5,240 42.8,240 50.8,234.7 53.9,234.7 55.3,237 58.2,234.7`,
    },
  },
];


var svgmap = new Vue({
  el: '#svgmap',
  data: {
    communes: cities
  }
})
```

```css
text {
    font-size: 7px;
    fill: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI'
}

svg{
  border:1px solid red;
 max-width :50vw;
}

polygon{
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
<svg id="svgmap"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    x="0px"
    y="0px"
    viewBox="0 200 200 400"
    xml:space="preserve"
    pointer-events="auto"
  >
    <g id="city-areas" >
        <polygon v-for="city in communes"
          class="interactive-map__polygon"
          :points="city.map.polygonPoints"
        />
    </g>
  
    <g id="city-labels">
      <text  v-for="city in communes" :key="city.id"
        :transform="`matrix(1 0 0 1 ${city.map.positionX} ${city.map.positionY})`"
      >
        {{ city.name }}
      </text>   
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I see, i will try that, i've refactor the code to avoid doing a second loop, but it seems it's inevitable